# Remove duplicates based on multiple columns and grouping by different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Sample Data:

```
| Plant | Part | Action |
| ----- | ---- | ------ |
| 101 | 123 | Action1 |
| 101 | 123 | Action2 |
| 101 | 123 | Action3 |
| 101 | 123 | Action4 |
| 101 | 124 | Action2 |
| 101 | 124 | Action4 |
| 101 | 125 | Action1 |
| 101 | 125 | Action2 |
```

In the above sample data, I want to delete the rows with Action1, Action2, and Action3 where the same Plant-Part combinations appear in Action4. This is simplified from the actual use case for clarity (The names of the actions do not have numbers). If the plant-part is not in Action4 then it should remain in whatever Actions (1,2,3) it was in before. The plant-part combinations could be in all Actions or none or any combination in between.

Desired Result:

```
| Plant | Part | Action |
| ----- | ---- | ------ |
| 101 | 123 | Action4 |
| 101 | 124 | Action4 |
| 101 | 125 | Action1 |
| 101 | 125 | Action2 |
```

I feel like this is relatively simple, but I can't seem to get the grouping right or wrap my head around it.

Comment: Be great to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to require a simple correlation using *exists*:

```
delete from t
where exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t2.plant = t.plant and t2.part = t.part 
    and t2.action = 'action4' 
    and t.action in ('Action1','Action2','Action3')
);
```

See result in [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ClEwck_P)

Answer (score 0):

We mark every time `action = 'action4'`, use `count() over()` partitioned by `plant` and `part` to make groups out of them. If `action4` is in the group we present that one and if not we present the entire group.

```
select  *
from    (
        select   Plant
                ,Part
                ,case when count(case when action = 'action4' then 1 end) over(partition by plant, part) < 1 then action when action = 'action4' then action end as Action 
        from    t
        ) t
where   action is not null
```

| Plant | Part | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 123 | Action4 |
| 101 | 124 | Action4 |
| 101 | 125 | Action1 |
| 101 | 125 | Action2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QMPgA6NF)

Answer (score -1):

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM #TestTable t1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM #TestTable
    WHERE [Action] IN ('Action4') -- I used 'IN' because there's more than just this
    ) t2 ON t1.Plant = t2.Plant AND t1.PartNumber = t2.PartNumber
WHERE t1.[Action] IN ('Action1', 'Action2', 'Action3')
```

This is what I ended up doing, probably a more elegant way...